# opengl java loading png textures not working properly

Tags: java, opengl, textures

I am trying to load a png file as a texture but, even though I do not have any error, I am not able to see the texture. The only thing I get is a square of one color. I have already searched for examples and I do not see what is the mistake I am doing. Here is the code:

```
        final Image image = SWTImageFactory.getImage(ImageFactory.CROSS_SYMBOL_IMAGE);
        final ImageData imageData = image.getImageData();

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4*imageData.width * imageData.height);
        int p, r, g, b, a;

        for (int y = 0; y<imageData.height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < imageData.width; x++) {

                p =  imageData.getPixel(x, y);
                a = (p >> 24) & 0xFF;  // get pixel bytes in ARGB order
                r = (p >> 16) & 0xFF;
                g = (p >> 8) & 0xFF;
                b = (p >> 0) & 0xFF;

                buffer.put((byte)r);   // fill in bytes in RGBA order
                buffer.put((byte)g);
                buffer.put((byte)b);
                buffer.put((byte)a); 
             }
        }

        buffer.rewind();
        gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4,imageData.width, imageData.height,0,
                        GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        int [] textures = new int [1];
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0); 

        gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.GL_REPEAT);
        gl.glTexParameteri (GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.GL_REPEAT);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL.GL_LINEAR);

        gl.glTexEnvf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL.GL_MODULATE);  

        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);

        gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(100.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f);

        gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(100.0f, 200.0f, 0.0f);

        gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(200.0f, 200.0f, 0.0f);

        gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glVertex3f(200.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f);

        gl.glEnd();
        gl.glDisable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I hope you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `gl.glTexImage2D` before any texture is bound (or maybe some other texture is bound), but this function changes the texture image of the currently bound texture object. So in your code you should rather call it after `gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0])`.

And by the way, I hope this code isn't called each frame (which the draw functions hint at), as you should not create a new texture object (let aside read an image from HDD) every frame (let aside you don't actually delete it). You should actually create the texture object in some initialization code, put an image into it and adjust its parameters, so that in the drawing code you only have to call `glBindTexture` (and maybe `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` or similar things).